# How to add a gradient to a card in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gradient, card

I'm trying to achieve this design:

[image]

I also want to use a `Card` widget provided by Flutter. It comes with some nice theming support that I'd like to use (`CardTheme`).

So don't know how to give a `LinearGradient` to a `Card`. Here's what I tried to do with combining a `Card` with `Container`:

```
Card(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            cardBorderColor,
            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          ],
          stops: [0, 0.8],
        ),
      ),
      child: ...
```

[image]

As you can see, the border radius of the card is respected when positioning the Container.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? is it the hard edge of the container?

Comment: @MoazEl-sawaf, my issue is that I don't want to specify `borderRadius` in a bunch of places. I just want to use the `Card` widget, set its gradient and let it figure out its own border radius (`CardTheme`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `clipBehavior` property of the `Card` to `Clip.antiAlias` achieves the desired outcome:

```
Card(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, // <-- this did the trick
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            cardBorderColor,
            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          ],
          stops: [0, 0.8],
        ),
      ),
      child: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `DecoratedBox` instead of `Container`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Yes, can you please provide a code sample? This doesn't seem to work for me (I don't get the rounded border)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(x),` there, and wrap everything with `ClipRRect` for `Card` color. You may have good reason to have `Card` and I don't know that, but you check  [Material](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html) widget and with it will be simple to archive, like not to handling extra border/override color of by `Card`.

**Result**
[image]

**Widget**

```dart
class DX extends StatelessWidget {
  const DX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      body: Center(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35), //* you can  increase it
          child: Card(
            color: Colors
                .transparent, //* or set the bg Color and remove [ClipRRect]
            child: Container(
              width: 400,
              height: 100,
              // margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),

              decoration: BoxDecoration(
               border: Border.all(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Colors.red,
                    // cardBorderColor,
                    Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                  ],
                  stops: [0, 0.8],
                ),
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text("asdasd")),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works, but I can as easily just specify `borderRadius` on the decoration of the `Container` inside the `Card`. My goal is not to use `borderRadius` as I want it to be set by the `CardTheme`.

Comment: how about removing border from container and just using clipRRect

Comment: Yeah, the `clipBehavior` property on the `Card` did the trick. I guess it's similar to a standalone `ClipRRect`.